# Ansible: Remove last comma in nested loop?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have the following in a jinja2 template. Essentially I'm looping through a dictionary, picking out the name and if it doesn't start with "sh", I'm adding it to this config. However, I would like to have the server comma separated.

```yaml
servers = {% for item in list_search_peers.json['entry'] %}{% if not item.name.startswith('sh-') %}{{ item.name }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

Normally i would do something like:

```yaml
servers = {% for item in list_search_peers.json['entry'] %}{% if not item.name.startswith('sh-') %}{{ item.name }}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endif %}{% endfor %}`
```

However `loop.last` won't work because I am filtering out one of the values.

My output is:

```yaml
servers = x.x.x.x:8089,y.y.y.y:8089,
```

But i want it without the last `,`:

```yaml
servers = x.x.x.x:8089,y.y.y.y:8089
```

I was trying `{% set }` to set a variable but had no luck there.

Answer (score 3):

Filter the list first. For example,

```yaml
  my_list: "{{ list_search_peers.json.entry|
               rejectattr('name', 'match', '^sh-(.*)$')|
               list }}"
```

then use it in the template

```
servers = {% for item in my_list %}{{ item.name }}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

---

Update

Create the list of the servers

```yaml
  servers: "{{ list_search_peers.json.entry|
               map(attribute='name')|
               reject('match', 'sh-') }}"
```

For example, given the data for testing

```yaml
  list_search_peers:
    json:
      entry:
        - name: x.x.x.x:8089
        - name: y.y.y.y:8089
        - name: sh-dummy
```

gives

```yaml
  servers:
  - x.x.x.x:8089
  - y.y.y.y:8089
```

Then, simply *join* the items in the template

```bash
servers = {{ servers|join(',') }}
```

gives

```bash
servers = x.x.x.x:8089,y.y.y.y:8089
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    list_search_peers:
      json:
        entry:
          - name: x.x.x.x:8089
          - name: y.y.y.y:8089
          - name: sh-dummy

    my_list: "{{ list_search_peers.json.entry|
                 rejectattr('name', 'match', 'sh-') }}"

    servers: "{{ list_search_peers.json.entry|
                 map(attribute='name')|
                 reject('match', 'sh-') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for item in list_search_peers.json['entry'] %}
          {% if not item.name.startswith('sh-') %}
          {{ item.name }}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
          {%- endif %}
          {%- endfor %}

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for item in my_list %}
          {{ item.name }}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
          {%- endfor %}

    - debug:
        var: servers

    - debug:
        msg: |
          servers = {{ servers|join(',') }}
```